# Client side data storage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following situation: the user submits a form, I fetch the data from the server via an Ajax request and displays a chart. However, I want to give the user the option to display the data in the chart in table form or export as csv after he had submitted the form.

I was wondering what's the best solution to store the data, considering that I don't want the data to persist if the user opens a new window to submit the form again for example.

The application is in Rails.

Thanks.

Comment: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/web-storage/

Comment: What do you mean you do not want the data to persist if they open a new window? Means they can have multiple windows and multiple sets of data that do not relate?

Comment: Please mark correct the right answer, or at least upvote answers that help!

Comment: @epascarello, I mean that if the user opens a new window and submits the same form, the app fetchs new data from the server depending on some filters in the form; so the multiple data sets do not relate.

Comment: @Liam, voting up requires 15 reputations which I don't have yet :( However, the answers are helpful indeed.

Comment: Aaaa i didnt know that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

Cookies
LocalStorage
SessionStorage

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Non-standard:

window.name can store anywhere from 1mb up to 10mb depending on the browser. This is more of a hack, but is fairly stable. You would need to implement your own accessor/setter methods on this, where localStorage and sessionStorage have API's built in.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i would recommend local storage if all your users browsers support it.

Its very simple to use and you can access it using these to methods.

```
localStorage.getItem("Itemkey");
localStorage.setItem("Itemkey","value");
localStorage.removeItem("ItemKey");
```

Its always a good way to go and this means you can assign each window a differnt local storage key and even remove the item when the window is closed, or unloaded !

For reference I found this very useful: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

And combine it with storing JSON objects ( http://www.json.org/js.html ) and you have a very fast,simple and easy to use solution. OR even just store a string,array or what ever is required.