# Is it possible to get a variable from another html

Tags: javascript

For example
I have a calculation.

```
<script>
  function hitung() {

    var hf = 0.0;
    var lebar = 0.6;
    var tinggi = 0.8;
    var total = 0.0;

    if (e == "hpl") {

      hf = 1.7;
    } else if (e == "cat") {
      hf = 2.0;
    } else {
      hf = 0.0;
    }
    total = lebar * tinggi * hf;
    document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML = (total);
  }
</script>
```

And I have another HTML contain a form with dompdf extension.

```
<form action="topdf.php" method="POST">
```

And my question is it possible I insert my calculation results to my dompdf?
If it possible, what I supposed to do?

Comment: So you want to set `total` inside another HTML document ?

Comment: yes @Accountantم

Comment: as far as I know  a javascript code lives only inside it's own HTML document, however you can save some data on the client browser so it can be shared between many HTML documents , see this ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785461/client-side-data-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785461/client-side-data-storage))

Comment: Or, another way is by building the second HTML document dynamically (by PHP) by passing the `total` to it as a normal http parameter like `topdf.php?total=500` *I prefer doing it this way*

Comment: i think thats isnt working, because if i change the `total` in my first html ,
it will not change in the dompdf

Comment: do you mean that you want your client to open 2 HTML documents in 2 different browser windows/tabs and do some changes in the first document and the second opened document get effected in the same time ?

Comment: almost right but i just want the second document to retrieve data from the first one

Comment: If the second document is already opened, then as I told you one option is by using `localStorage` . Set the value by the first document by `localStorage.setItem("total","500");` and check the variable on the second document by a timer `localStorage.getItem("total");`, However a web application is depending on requests and responses it's not supposed to be working in this way (2 opened documents play with each other in the same time)